# GCP instance cannot parse fastai resource

Tags: google-compute-engine

Trying to connect to a Jupyter Notebook in the instance through the shell, however it throws an error message informing that "the resource" could not be parsed.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3zm5.png)

This is a Windows server with an Ubuntu terminal, running fastai. The Notebook is already installed and set up, and I already increased my GPU quota to 1.

Interestingly enough, the error comes up regardless of whether the instance is running or not.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion maybe you need to explicitly specify the project name where the instance is located. Execute:

```
 $ gcloud config set project your_project_id
```

Also you have to make sure that you are logged in with the right account. Execute:

```
$ gcloud auth login
```

And finally to be sure that you are using the right command, go to Cloud Console, locate your instance and click on the drop down menu saying "SSH", select "View gcloud command" and use this to do the connection.